# Declaring inputs in the component declaration instead using @Input?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

The Angular Material Toolbar is declared like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mat-toolbar',
  exportAs: 'matToolbar',
  templateUrl: 'toolbar.html',
  styleUrls: ['toolbar.css'],
  inputs: ['color'],
...

})
```

Is using `inputs: ['color]` in the component declaration the same as putting `@Input() color` in the class body?

Also anyone know what the purpose of `exportAs` is?

Comment: Check out the docs: https://angular.io/api/core/Directive

Comment: I did but it's so generic ... for example for `exportAs` it says: `Defines the name that can be used in the template to assign this directive to a variable.`

Comment: There are examples on that page, too.

Comment: OK - I looked at the export as example and it looks like it allows us to take what would be an element / component directive and turn it into an attribute directive, IIUC.  So for example if we wanted to take a `div` and turn it into a `mat-toolbar` component we could do `<div matToolbar ...>` essentially upgrading a div element to a `mat-toolbar` component?  I assume the `div` then also gets properties like `color` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exportAs: 'matToolbar'` allows  you to make use of your toolbar in the template. example:

```
<mat-toolbar #myToolbarReference="matToolbar">
...
</mat-toolbar>
{{myToolbarReference.color}}
```

this property says that the component instance (here MatToolbarComponent instance) could be exported from this element via `matToolbar` string.

Comment: Cool - I was always wondering why they assigned the tag to a value like that.  Any thoughts on the `input` part?

Comment: `inputs` is the same as marking all the inputs with `@Input` decorator